# To check if given set is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\{(x,y)|xy=1\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$. Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider $f_1:A \to R$ given by $f_1(x,y)=x+a$ and $f_2:A \to R$ given by $f_2(x,y)=y$.

Question asks if set $\{(x,y)|f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)\}$ is closed.

Here's my try:
$f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y) \implies x+a=y \implies x+a=\frac{1}{x}$, which can be rearranged as $x^2+ax-1=0$,which has two roots. Hence given set is finite and hence closed.

Topologies used are usual ones.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Without computation: if two functions are continuous (and go to a Hausdorff space) the set on which they coincide is always closed in the domain.

Comment: $\{(x,y)|f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)\}$ is not a finite set. It contains $(x,x+a)$ for every real number $x$, so the set is uncountable.

Comment: define $F:A\to\mathbb{R}$ to be the difference of $f_1$ and $f_2$. your set is equal to $F^{-1}(\{0\})$. by continuity, this set is closed. u need only show that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Right. But I am unable to figure out what went wrong in my argument.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma is projection is the keyword showing both functions are continuous

Comment: No it’s not IMO. $f_2$ is a projection OK but $f_1$ is not.

Comment: @ Yes. For $f_1$ it is composition of projection and translation. So that's continuous I guess.